# MVVMLight - ModernWindow - Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm-light, idataerrorinfo

I have an issue with view validation using IDataErrorInfo in my model object.
I have an application with several pages using ModernWindow control.

At startup, the validation is working fine. But once I navigated one time on the view, when I come back to one of the view already visited the validation don't work any more but IDataErrorInfo valiation method is called, something miss me in the knowledge of the functioning of the framework.

If someone has already encountered this problem, he is welcome

Sample code for ViewModel :

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
     public readonly IDataAccessService ServiceProxy;
     private User _myUser
     public User MyUser
     {
         get { return _myUser; }
         set
      {
          _myUser= value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("MyUser");
      }
  }

   public MyViewModel(IDataAccessService serviceProxy)
{
    ServiceProxy = serviceProxy;
    MyUser = new User();

    ReadAllCommand = new RelayCommand(GetUsers);
    SaveCommand = new RelayCommand<User>(SaveUser);
    SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchUser);
    SendProctorCommand = new RelayCommand<User>(SendUser);
    DeleteProctorCommand = new RelayCommand<User>(DeleteUser);
    ReceiveUser();

}
private void ReceiveUser()
{
    if (Proctor != null)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<MessageCommunicator>(this, (user) => {
            this.MyUser= user.User;
        });
    }
}

private  void SendUser(User user)
{
    if (user!= null)
    {

        Messenger.Default.Send<MessageCommunicator>(new MessageCommunicator()
        {
            User = user
        });                             
    }
}
```

The entity code (only those parts which concern the problem) :

```
public partial class User : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
{


[NotMapped]
public string Error
{
    get
    {
        return this[null];
    }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;
        if (columnName == "Lastname")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lastname))
                result = "Please enter a lastname";
            else
            if (Lastname.Length < 5)
                result = "The lastname must have 5 characters at least";
        }

        ...
        return result;
    }
  }
```

A sample for one field in the XAML :

```
 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="LastnameTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path= MyUser.Lastname  ,Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" LostFocus="LastnameTextBox_LostFocus" />
```

TextBoxStyle.Xaml :

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="StandardTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                    <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="10"
                                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                        <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                    </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>

</Style>
```

Comment: Can you give us your code

Comment: Please try the following: wrap your relevant XAML part in an `<AdornerDecorator>` element. In some special cases, the error template visualization becomes flawed when the adorner layer is shared. I observed a possibly similar problem for `TabControl` in one of my projects and solved it by using a separate adorner layer for each `TabItem`. I don't really know whether your problem is the same.

Comment: grek40, sorry I forgot to join the textboxstyle file code. I already use it. How ever, I noticed that once the ViewModelLocator through IOC mechanism got the viewmodel instance the sendUser method wasn't called anymore. The RaisePropertyChanged of the MyUser object aren't triggered anymore as well.

Comment: Are you sure we are talking about the same thing? `AdornerDecorator` is not `AdornedElementPlaceholder`... also its not clear to me, when and why you expect the `sendUser` and the propertychange notifications. Hint: When you comment here in response to someone specific, please write @username to notify the user.

Comment: @grek40, thanks for your trick about *username, I will check for AdornedElementPlaceholder. Maybe for SendUser, it s just because I m not totally mastering this framework (first project with it) so I misunderstood something. Let me check. Anyway thanks for your time

Comment: @grek40 You were right, using the AdornerDecorator fixed my problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the window `AdornerLayer` doesn't properly update when inner views change. I observed this for `TabControl`, where switching between tabs didn't always trigger the correct adorner updates. Other types of view-changing controls are probably affected by the same thing.

The solution is to specify adorner layers that are specific to the controls that will be rendered/hidden dynamically. A local `AdornerLayer` is created by wraping controls in an `AdornerDecorator`.

In case of `TabControl`, the transformation would be as follows:

```
<!-- Before -->
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <Content/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>

<!-- After -->
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <Content/>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Your layout should have some similar container/content layout, where the `AdornerDecorator` can be included.

Comment: Sure you were totally right in your previous comment I fixed it by this way ;)